# Unset variable at the end of if else statement

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, unset

I am using 2 if else statements where the first set just displays 4 results, and the second should display all results (including the initial 4)

I have got the counter working but it also effects the second set of results (which only displays the remaining results minus the first 4) and I can't work out how to unset the variable.

I have tried using 'unset' in different places, also tried setting a new rule for the second batch but nothing works. Unset works at different places but also unsets the initial 4, thereby displaying all on both.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<section>

    <div class="full-width-inner">
        <div class="find-anything-mobile-grid">

            <?php if ( have_rows( 'carousel_search_item' ) ) : ?>
            <?php $i = 0; ?>
                <?php while ( have_rows( 'carousel_search_item' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                <?php $i++; ?>
                <?php if( $i > 4 ): ?>
                    <?php break; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
        
                <div class="lenses-carousel-slide">
                    <p>content</p>
                </div>  
        
                <?php unset($i); ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
                
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php // No rows found ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>  

            
        <div class="find-anything-mobile-grid-popup">
            
                <?php if ( have_rows( 'carousel_search_item' ) ) :  ?>
                
                    <?php while ( have_rows( 'carousel_search_item' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
                    
                    <div class="lenses-carousel-popup-item">
                        <p>content</p>
                    </div>  
                
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php // No rows found ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                
        </div>  
    
            
    </div>  


</section>
```

Comment: `unset($i)` should work. Why do you think it's not working? The rest of the code never uses `$i`, so why do you think you need to unset it?

Comment: Putting `<?php ... ?>` on every line really makes your code hard to read.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the variable. `the_row()` doesn't care about the variable. It just displays the next row in the results. So the second loop starts where the first loop ended, it doesn't go back to the beginning.

Comment: What library is `the_row()` from? There's probably a function to reset it back to the beginning, which you should call before the second loop.

Comment: Hi @Barmar

<?php $i = 0; ?>

Is set right at the beginning. Sorry about all the <?php's. This is using Advanced custom fields but I checked their documentation and couldn't find anything. 

In terms of it having nothing to do with the variable, does this mean there is NO way to reset the counter?

Answer (score 1):

`$i` has no effect on the rows that are printed with `the_row()`.

To go back to the first row, use the undocumented function `reset_rows('carousel_search_item')` between the two loops.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly comment, but space there is limited.

Your code is virtually unreadable. Please go and have a look at some PHP style guides. If your code contains `?>[whitespace]<?php` then its wrong. Removing that is slightly better but its still confused. Why do you have empty 'else' blocks?

Cleaning this up, makes some of the bugs more obvious (to me at least):

```
<?php 
  if ( have_rows( 'carousel_search_item' ) ) : 
    $i = 0; 
    while ( have_rows( 'carousel_search_item' ) ) : 
        the_row(); 
        $i++; 
        if( $i > 4 ):
            break; 
        endif; ?>
            <div class="lenses-carousel-slide">
                 <p>content</p>
            </div>  
        <?php 
        unset($i); 
    endwhile; ?>
  endif; ?>
        </div>          
            <div class="find-anything-mobile-grid-popup">
                 <?php 
                 if ( have_rows( 'carousel_search_item' ) ) :  
                     while ( have_rows( 'carousel_search_item' ) ) : 
                         the_row(); ?>
                         <div class="lenses-carousel-popup-item">
                            <p>content</p>
                         </div>  
                        <?php 
                     endwhile;
                  endif; 
                  ?>  
            </div>  
</div>
```

(but stackoverflow's syntax highlighter can't make sense of this)

We don't know what "have_rows()" and "the_row()" are doing - but it smells like they are operating on the same data which is not being passed as a parameter. That's BAD.

You have 2 exits from your loop defined in different places. That;s BAD.

You are using $i as way of limiting the loop - but unsetting this variable in the middle of the loop. That's BAD.

> second set of results (which only displays the remaining results minus the first 4

Unless you are doing something really, REALLY bad with scope then you've got malleable state inside "the_row()" - which is also BAD.

Move your data pointer outside of your functions.

Given the description of what you are trying to achieve, I would have written something like:

```
$spacer='';
for ($i=0; $i<4 && $i<count($data); $i++) {
   print $spacer;
   output($data[$i]);
   $spacer="<div class=\"lenses-carousel-slide\">\n<p>content</p>\n</div>\n";
}
print "<div class=\"find-anything-mobile-grid-popup\">\n";
foreach ($data as $d) {
    print $d . "\n";
    print $spacer;
}
print "</div>\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I did try to clean this up before posting. The original code was REALLY long.

This is using Advanced custom fields, which I should have stated. I didn't realise these functions were so specific to it.

I knew I was unsetting the loop in the wrong place - I just left that attempt in there because I was trying to illustrate that I had been making attempts. I tried it in lots of different places.

I only really know the VERY basics in php and am still trying to get my head around it. Thankfully @barmar has answered this for me with an undocumented function.

Comment: After a quick Google, I think you are referring to the "Advanced custom fields" Wordpress plugin. While I think I know why they are handling state in a distributed manner like this, that doesn't in any way justify it. Learning to program from bad code is perhaps not the best approach. Jumping in at the deep end and trying to integrate your own code with that from 2 different teams is also not a good place to start.

Comment: ACF is a very well known and widely used plugin and all the code in my example is straight from the documentation, but I had just never used a variable counter with it before, or at least never needed to unset it. I am very well rehearsed with php when it comes to ACF, but you are correct in that I don't know much outside of what I need to know to use the plugin so merging the two, albeit for a seemingly basic function, can be difficult for me.

Comment: If you want to learn how to program, watch some of Uncle Bob's videos on Youtube.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the tip